# Using get_model in a custom slug generator raises django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: django

I created a custom slug generator function to use in multiple models across multiple apps.  To achieve this I pass the relevant django app name and django model as string parameters to the function, so the function can check if the slug is unique for that model:

```
def slug_generator(django_app, django_model, field_name, slug_len, prefix=""):
    unique_pk = False
    model = apps.get_model(django_app, django_model)
    while not unique_pk:
        random_pks = random.sample(
            string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase, slug_len)
        new_pk = ''.join(random_pks)
        search_query = {field_name: new_pk}
        try:
            if not model.objects.filter(**search_query).exists():
                unique_pk = True
        except:
            if not model.objects.all().exists():
                unique_pk = True

    return prefix + new_pk
```

called in models.py like so:

```
class Form(models.Model):
    form_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=25, default=slug_generator('forms', 'Form', 'form_id', 25))
```

The function was working fine when I only was using it for a single model (so i wasn't using get_model, I just hard coded the model it was for). Since adding get_model, this error is thrown on startup django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

I tried putting the following before my function:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

It only led me to a new error RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant, so it makes me think that there is a better way to write the function.  Is what I am trying to achieve possible or should I just refactors the string generation portion out of the function and make a slug_generator function for each model with the model names hard coded in?

Answer (score 0):

Realised it's because I am actually calling the function in the Form field by providing it parameters. I changed it to the following and got it running:

```
def get_slug():
    return slug_generator('forms', 'Form', 'form_id', 25)

class Form(models.Model):
    form_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=25, default=get_slug)
```

not sure if there is a more elegant way to do it though